# IntelliBot @SeleniumLibrary Patched plugin does not work on PyCharm (mac)

Tags: pycharm, selenium

I have installed PyCharm 2019.1.2 (Community Edition) on my mac and then I installed IntelliBot @SeleniumLibrary Patched plugin. The plug in does not work at all. The robot files are not recognized, I cannot create new robot files, no syntax highlighting, nothing related to the plugin works.

I have reinstalled PyCharm, plugin, Python. No effect at all.

PyCharm 2019.1.2 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-191.7141.48, built on May 7, 2019
JRE: 11.0.2+9-b159.56 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14.3

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the file type register pattern. The *.robot file was put to Python and not to Robot Feature.
To change that:

1. Go to Preferences-> Editor -> File Types.
2. Select Robot Feature.
3. In Register Patterns section, click + sign to add new pattern.
4. Provide *.robot
5. If you are asked about resigning wildcard, accept it.

[FileTypes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9sCh.png)